# How can I use Word's Table of Contents, after deleting Word's default style names with 'Heading' in them?

Tags: microsoft-word

I like Style Names to stipulate the typeface, color and size. Thus I renamed some of Word's default ones and deleted unnecessary others like Heading 1, Heading 2.

Like p. 178 of [*Word 2019 in easy steps*](http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/word-2019-easy-steps/) (on the left beneath), p. 457 of 
Joan Lambert's [*Microsoft Word 2019 Step by Step*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1509305874) contends

> By default, Word creates a table of contents based on the document headings (as indicated by the styles  Heading 1, Heading 2, and so on).

How can I compel Word to acknowledge my Style Names? Or how else can I solve this?

The right screenshot beneath proves that Word blocked my attempt to change my Style Name to Heading 1, although I already deleted Heading 1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter the built-in styles, just create a new one and call it what you want. Once you've created the style, you can then use it as a TOC level. To do that, go to the *References* tab and select *Table of Contents* on the far left. Select *Custom Table of Contents . . .* and click on the "Options" tab. Look for your style and set the TOC level. You can customize the format as well by selecting the *Modify* button.